# Edit frontend footer link from admin panel configuration section magento 2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, frontend

I have a custom module that displays a custom link in the footer section in frontend.
Further, I have created my module specific configurations in the admin panel.

I would like to add option to admin panel for Disable/Enable the link on frontend's footer.

How can I achieve this? Please help.

I have added the footer link in frontend in view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="Name">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My custom link</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path/to/link</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

My system.xml is like,

```
        <!--For creating section -->
    <section id="quotes" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="320" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <label>Module</label>

        <!--Assign section to tab -->
        <tab>mytab</tab>
        <resource>Vendor_Module::configuration</resource>

        <!--create group for fields in section -->
        <group id="quotes" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Group Name</label>

            <!--create text type field -->
            <field id="enabled" translate="label comment" sortOrder="7" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Enable the link</label>
                <comment>select from the dropdown</comment>

                <!-- source model which we created for drop down options -->
                <source_model>Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Module</source_model>
            </field>
        </group> 
    </referenceBlock>
```

The Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Module contains,

```
    /**
 * @return array
 */
public function toOptionArray() {
    return [
        ['value' => 'Yes', 'label' => __('Yes')],
        ['value' => 'No', 'label' => __('No')],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was successful to achieve this. Posting it in case it might help someone in future.

Created a helper.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
 */
protected $scopeConfig;

const XML_PATH_ENABLED = 'section/group/field';

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig) {
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

 /**
  * Sample function returning config value
  * */
public function getEnabled() {
    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;

    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::XML_PATH_ENABLED, $storeScope);
}
```

Called this into my template file,

```
$helper = $this->helper('path/to/helper');
echo $value = $helper->getEnabled();
```

Also in view/frontend/layout/default.xml where I added the footer link, I was missing the ifconfig. Added the same.

```
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" ifconfig="section/group/field" name="name">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My custom link</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">path/to/link</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

At first add config to your module.
in file `module/etc/adminhtml/system.xml` add:

```
            <field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                   showInStore="1">
                <label>Enabled</label>
                <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
            </field>
```

In section and group that you want to display it. It should be actually exist one for your module.

For getting value of this option you have to create Helper eg `module/Helper/Admin/Config.php`(or add only function if this is exist) and make constructor:

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
)
{
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
```

then function:

```
/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isActive()
{
    return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('your_section/your_group/active');
}
```

Almost done.

You have to just find where link is displaying and check what value if for `active` option.

Comment: I have added the config for my module. Also created the Helper. But I dont seem to find a way to diable/enable a footer link in frontend with the config in adminhtml. I am really new to magento 2 so please bear with me.

Comment: Find in your module place where link is adding to footer. I can not help you with that at all cause It id custom module and I have no idea how it works and looks :c When You will find that place, Ill help You with problems

Comment: Can u please have a look at the edited question once?